# How to Set environment $PATH for flutter in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: ubuntu, flutter, terminal, path, environment

I looked for [documentations](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#get-sdk)  , too looked for [update your PATH](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path)

The file that I used in step 4(update your path) **/home/paulo/.bashrc**
but not working for me, then when reboot my system, open my terminal and type **flutter**, return **"flutter: command not found"**.

How could I get that after start my system the command **flutter** simply work?

English is not my first language, so tell me if there was any misundestanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try these steps :

```
cd $HOME

gedit .bashrc
```

the bashrc will be opened, then add the sdk path to file :[image]

```
export PATH=~/your_path_to_your_flutter_sdk/flutter/bin:$PATH

source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: Work now and support reboot.